# Where is the RecyclerView in the support library?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library

I'm working on an app which uses the RecyclerView component. I was checking my build.gradle file and it had these dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta5'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
```

There was no 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1', and yet I had a RecyclerView (android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView) in the project.

Which of the packages above also contains the RecyclerView? Or is there something I don't understand about the support library packages?

Comment: You can find that in google very easily. Otherwise add it to the view using the design view in Android Strudio which adds the library for you.

Comment: I have reasons to believe it's this one 
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
for more information visit https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: check out https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html for the full list of support libs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which of the packages above also contains the RecyclerView?

None of them. `RecyclerView` is in `recyclerview-v7`.

> Or is there something I don't understand about the support library packages?

`design` has a transitive dependency upon `recyclerview-v7`. Hence, by depending upon `design`, your app also depends upon `recyclerview-v7`. This is handled for you automatically.

You could simplify your dependencies further, as `design` depends upon `appcompat-v7`, so you do not need to request `appcompat-v7` yourself:

```
// compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta5'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
```

Then, comment out the `support-v4` dependency and see if you have build problems. Most likely, what you are using from there is pulled in by something else already, and so you will not need that dependency in your `build.gradle` file either.

You can read more about transitive dependencies [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#view-dependency-tree).

Comment: I see. `design` doesn't **contain** the code for `RecyclerView` but it depends upon the package that does. I commented out `appcompat` and `support-v4` and it compiled without erros. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score -1):

just add it in your app gradle

compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1