# RecyclerView dependencies in android(androidx)?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I used implementation `'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'` for RecycleView. In layout when I'm typing "recycle" it gives suggestion as `androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$RecycleListView` which is not what I want.

Even though I'm typing this `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView` it works but it doesn't let used attributes like id, height, width, etc. inside. It was working fine one month ago like it was giving proper suggestion now it completely not showing for RecycleView. Does anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
```

Update

Here is a list of some libraries in my `build.gradle`:

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

Also see [Where is the RecyclerView in the support library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46633995/where-is-the-recyclerview-in-the-support-library) and [How to import RecyclerView for Android L-preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440852/how-to-import-recyclerview-for-android-l-preview).

[image]

Comment: no it is still giving me the suggestion as "androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$RecycleListView" ..got any other solution?

Comment: @IRONMAN, please, show your `build.gradle` and an error.

Comment: see..I'm not getting error ok...I have added your your dependencies in my Gradle but its not giving me the proper suggestion for recycle view in xml...it gives me something like "androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$RecycleListView"

Comment: @IRONMAN, I added a picture.

Comment: First of all remove your all dependency related to `RecyclerView` then go to your xml and then switch to design you will see `RecyclerView`  with download arrow click on that arrow.

Comment: I got it...all I did is restart my project...thanks

Comment: Thank you for acceptance of the anser, friend @AshwiniJ.

Answer (score 2):

- First of all remove your all dependency related to `RecyclerView`, then go to your XML and then switch to design. You will see `RecyclerView` with download arrow. Click on that arrow.
- This will add a dependency according to your SDK version. No need to add particular version for that.This will do by itself.

[image]

Comment: Happy to help!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 1.Open build.gradle and add recycler view dependency. 

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1' 

2. left corner of this file sync now option and click on it.

3. in xml file you can add below code:

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
 android:id="@+id/listing"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```